# Get selected items from listview using custom adapter on submit button pressed in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have created my own adapter, InteractiveArrayAdapter, and set it to as adapter for the listview (MyListView) I have in my xml layout file, let's say MyActivity. Then, from MyActivity activity, I perform this:

**MyActivity.java**:

```
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);

        ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this, model);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My custom adapter uses a custom model, Model, that I have created to work with each element in the listview. Each listview item, consists of a TextView and a CheckBox.

My goal is to obtain the complete list of checked items when user press a submit button placed in the MyActivity xml layout file so I perform the following steps to get rid of this:

1. In my custom adapter, InteractiveArrayAdapter, I declare a private Set to store the identifiers of each element selected in the listview. I use my own identifier insteaf of using the position in the list. This identifier comes from the primary key in the database from where in a previous step I have extracted all the desired items to populate the listview. As identifiers for items cannot be repeated, I use a Set. This Set is updated each time an item in the listview is checked or unchecked. Also I implement a public method to return this set.

   ```
   public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

   ...

   private Set<Integer> checked = new HashSet<Integer>();

   ...

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View view = null;

       viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.interactiveRowCheck);
       viewHolder.checkbox
               .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                                boolean isChecked) {
                       Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                               .getTag();
                       element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                       Integer id = element.getId();
                       if (isChecked) {
                           checked.add(id);
                       } else if (checked.contains(id)) {
                           checked.remove(id);
                       }
                   }
               });
   }

   public Set<Integer> getCheckedItems() {
       return this.checked;
   }
   }
   ```
2. in **MyActivity.java** I handle click on the button and I try to read the
   list of items checked by doing this:

   ```
   public void OnClickCompareButton(View view) {
       InteractiveArrayAdapter adapter;

       Set<Integer> checkedItems = adapter.getCheckedItems();
       Iterator<Integer> it = checkedItems.iterator();

       int size = checkedItems.size();
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           // Do whatever...
       }
   }
   ```

But Android Studio is throwing an error on compiling:

```
Error:(82, 37) error: variable adapter might not have been initialized
```

If then I use the variable **adapter** initialized at the beginning of this post when setting the adapter, that is:

```
    public void OnClickCompareButton(View view) {
        Set<Integer> checkedItems = this.adapter.getCheckedItems();
        Iterator<Integer> it = checkedItems.iterator();

        int size = checkedItems.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            // Do whatever...
        }
    }
```

below error is shown on compiling:

```
Error:(82, 49) error: cannot find symbol method getCheckedItems()
```

So how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error:(82, 37) error: variable adapter might not have been initialized

This is indeed the case - `adapter` had been declared just above and not initialised, so would be `null` anyway if the compiler hadn't got there first.

Your second method seems, at a quick glance, much more likely to work, so:

> Error:(82, 49) error: cannot find symbol method getCheckedItems()

This is because the declared type of the Adapter is `ListAdapter` (see [getAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListAdapter%28%29), arguably the preferred way to access fields), not your subclass `InteractiveArrayAdapter`.

You could cast it:

```
Set<Integer> checkedItems = ((InteractiveArrayAdapter) getListAdapter()).getCheckedItems();
```

and to avoid confusion with the `ArrayAdapter` you could simplify the instantiation / passing to your view:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
listView.setAdapter(new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this, model));
```

Also, a couple of minor code style points:

- Probably best to make all your method names start with lower case, as per the [official Java standards](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).
- You can generally remove `this.` in a method (e.g. `return this.checked;` -> `return checked;`)

Comment: I have casted it to my custom adapter and now it works perfectly! Also a lot of thanks for your suggestions regarding to code style and that for simplifing the instantation. I will try to apply these rules from now on. Normally I use this prefix to refer objects declared in the class so I can distinguish them from those declared into the method in question so making the code more readable but in fact is the same.